# How can I use BQL to query data from another company context

Tags: acumatica

I'm using a graph extension to post data to the Journal Transaction screen in another company context using the following:

```
using (PXLoginScope ls = new PXLoginScope(companylogin))
```

The problem is that I want to query Account from the target company in order to get the accountID using the accountCD of the source company.  I've tried putting the BQL to select from Account under the PXLoginScope - but it doesn't seem to matter... it fetches records from the main company the graph extension is written in instead of the login scope of the other company.  Is there a way to use BQL in one company to get records from another company?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since no one posted an answer to this, I'm assuming there's no way to do this within Acumatica.

My solution was to create a view that fetches records for all companies, with an accompanying DAC so that I can use BQL to query and filter based on company.

Answer (score 0):

By design, inside PXLoginScope the framework executes all BQL queries inside the context of the PXLoginScope company. It does not matter inside what company context a BLC instance was initialized. The actual company context comes into play only during the time BQL queries are executed.

With that said, there is no way to request data from multiple companies at the same time. The recommended approach is to pre-fetch all necessary data from the source company before your code enters PXLoginScope for the target company.